# 0.1 <= 0.10 is returning false

Tags: python

I'm working on a python script and I'm not getting what I expect when comparing values at decimal places.  I'm pulling one value from an SQL query which is reading 0.10 to 40 decimal places. When I compare it to a python generated 0.1 it's telling me that pythons 0.1 is greater than the SQL 0.1.  I know it's something to do with the rounding of numbers but how do I resolve it.  I could just 0.0000001 to the SQL number but I would prefer a cleaner method.  Please see my examples below.

```
print(f"Dist: {round(abs(dist),2):.40f}, t.min_dbv: {round(0.10,2):.40f}")
print(f"Test 1: {round(abs(dist),2) <= round(0.10,2)}")
print(f"Dist: {round(abs(dist),2):.40f}, t.min_dbv: {round(t.min_dbv,2):.40f}")
print(f"Test 2: {round(abs(dist),2) <= round(t.min_dbv,2)}")
print(f"Dist: {Decimal(abs(dist)):.40f}, t.min_dbv: {Decimal(t.min_dbv):.40f}")
print(f"Test 3: {Decimal(abs(dist)) <= Decimal(t.min_dbv)}")
```

This returns the following

```
Dist: 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021182, t.min_dbv: 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021182
Test 1: True
Dist: 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021182, t.min_dbv: 0.1000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Test 2: False
Dist: 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021182, t.min_dbv: 0.1000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Test 3: False
```

As you can see I've tried round and Decimal

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) help at all?

Comment: `Decimal` doesn't really help unless you pass a *string* representing the decimal number you expect to be exact. `Decimal('0.1')` is fine; `Decimal(0.1)` isn't no more accurate than `0.1` itself.

Comment: Judging by the output you're showing here, it looks like `t.min_dbv` is probably a `Decimal`, and one that was constructed the *right* way, while `dist` is a float. If so, you need to construct `dist` as a `Decimal` *without* going through a float, as chepner says.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all the explanations and very quick response.

I got round this issue with the following code. I basically convert it to a string then back to a decimal.  Maybe not the correct way but the cleanest for me.

Decimal(np.format_float_positional(abs(dist))) <= t.min_dbv

Answer (score 0):

It's typical problem for floating numbers. Because there could be some diffrence, you need setup some treshold and make condition with this threshold.
There is pseudocode

```
threshold = 0.0000001
abs(a-b) <= threshold
```

You just need check if the diffrence between two values is smaller than treshold. You say that if it's in this threshold is ok for you to work with it.

Comment: yup, I was going to write the same answer